# How can i check for duplicate list in SharePoint using power app?

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

[How can i check for duplicate list in SharePoint using power app][1]s.

(Note : it is not a SharePoint list form.)

Event                                      EmailEmail

SharepointSaturday               Maruthi@gmail.com

Azure boot camp                    Maruthi@gmail.com

On click of submit ,user shouldn't able to register to the same event again.So how can i check this on click of submit button.

Appreciate your help.

I have two list :

1:Registration list : where i store/create the items on submit of button in powerapps

2: Events list : is source list ,where lookup Events column in powerapps.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`Filter()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-filter-lookup) function. If your data source is `Registration`, and you want to check if a duplicate exists for a given event of `event_id`, and email of `email` then you could do something like

```
Filter(Registartion,event_id=event_id,email=email)
```

If there are any results then you know not add a new one. You can check the length of the returned array using [`CountRows()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-table-counts) function

Answer (score 0):

something like this and prevent the submit function based on your condition.

```
If(CountRows(Filter(DataSource,Name = "Value1")) > 0,"Exist","Does Not Exist")
```

detailed expression like below

```
If(CountRows(Filter(DataSource,Name = "Value1")) > 0, Notify("You do not have the permission to submit a record.", NotificationType.Error ),SubmitForm(EditForm1))
```